# How to check friends count while signing app in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to check condition that if users friend count is greater than 10 then and only then he/she can sign in to App. How I will implement it in php facebook SDK. I need to handle it at my end or facebook provide some conditional check for that?

Comment: With the Graph API Explorer, I can get the user's friends... so maybe `if(count($userNode['friends']['data']) >= 10) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle it at your end. Simply, get the friends count of the user **after the user logs in**, using:

```
$result = $facebook->api("/me/friends");
if(count($result) > 10)
{
   // proceed
}
else
{
   // stop
}
```